# Revisit REP3 with respect to C++11?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a migration plan to C++11 in the works?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57728/revisit-rep3-with-respect-to-c++11?/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-11**:
Are you referring to this: "A wholesale jump to C++[0|1]x will not happen until all commonly used OS platforms fully support it."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have not reached the point that even all the Ubuntu platforms support C++11x.

A good [status page](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) for support shows we're still a ways away from general support.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-04-02**:
So are we essentially waiting for the most recent LTS Ubuntu to support GCC 4.8? Or are we happy with a reasonable subset of C++11? Once Lucid is no longer supported (i.e. 4 weeks from now), Precise offers GCC 4.6 and most of the useful bits of C++11.

**Comment by [en4bz](https://answers.ros.org/users/12126/en4bz/) on 2014-02-18**:
What is the current status of this? Indigo is going to support Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04 both of which ship with with gcc 4.8.[1|2] as per http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/gcc .

4.8.1 is C++11 feature complete http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/gcc-4.8.1-released-c11-feature-complete

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-12-23**:
Seems like ROS Jade might be a good time to support C++11

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-12-23**:
What does "ROS supporting C++11" mean? Requiring or supporting C++11? C++11 has been on by default for OS X for a quite a while now and ROS works fine there. I would not lightly *require* C++11 for Jade, because we don't need C++11 features and it would exclude systems without C++11.